# Read nested XML into dataframe

Tags: r, xml, xml-parsing

I can't read nested nodes into a data frame.
The XML has only two tags I'm intrested in (see example below) named "Caratula" and "DTE"
I managed to read "Caratula" without problems but "DTE" has nested nodes and I can't find a way to read them properly.
The R code I'm using is:

```
    # Carga las librerías necesarias.
library("XML")
library("methods")
library(xml2)
library(plyr)

#establece el directorio de trabajo
setwd("~/")

#coloca el nombre del archivo en una cadena
dte<-"Ejemplo.xml"

#carga el xml
a<-read_xml(dte)

#limpia los namespace
b<-xml_ns_strip(a)

#Parsea el xml en la librería XML
c<-xmlParse(b)

#genera el dataframe para la Caratula
Caratula <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(c,"//Caratula"))
```

With "DTE" I adapted a code from the web (sorry, I don't remember the source, but thanks). This code works very well when there is only one "Detalle" nested nodes in the file. But it fails with more than one "Detalle".

The code is:

```
    #genera el dataframe para los DTEs
d <- xmlParse(b, asText =  TRUE)
DTE <- do.call(rbind.fill, lapply(d['//DTE'], function(x) { 
  names <- xpathSApply(x, './/.', xmlName) 
  names <- names[which(names == "text") - 1]
  values <- xpathSApply(x, ".//text()", xmlValue)
  return(as.data.frame(t(setNames(values, names)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}))
```

Could you help me?

XML below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<EnvioDTE xmlns="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte EnvioDTE_v10.xsd">
 <SetDTE ID="SetDoc">
  <Caratula version="1.0">
   <RutEmisor>88888888-8</RutEmisor>
   <RutEnvia>8414240-9</RutEnvia>
   <RutReceptor>76576212-K</RutReceptor>
   <FchResol>2003-05-16</FchResol>
   <NroResol>0</NroResol>
   <TmstFirmaEnv>2016-10-04T14:01:13</TmstFirmaEnv>
   <SubTotDTE>
    <TpoDTE>33</TpoDTE>
    <NroDTE>2</NroDTE>
   </SubTotDTE>
  </Caratula>
 <DTE xmlns="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte" version="1.0">
 <Documento ID="T33">
  <Encabezado>
   <IdDoc>
    <TipoDTE>33</TipoDTE>
    <Folio>52725</Folio>
    <FchEmis>2016-10-04</FchEmis>
   </IdDoc>
   <Emisor>
    <RUTEmisor>88888888-8</RUTEmisor>
    <RznSoc>EMPRESA DE PRUEBA</RznSoc>
    <GiroEmis>Informatica</GiroEmis>
    <Acteco>1</Acteco>
    <CdgSIISucur>59529595</CdgSIISucur>
    <DirOrigen>Teatinos 120</DirOrigen>
    <CmnaOrigen>Santiago</CmnaOrigen>
    <CiudadOrigen>Santiago</CiudadOrigen>
   </Emisor>
   <Receptor>
    <RUTRecep>76576212-K</RUTRecep>
    <RznSocRecep>E-SERVICE SPA</RznSocRecep>
    <GiroRecep>Comercial</GiroRecep>
    <DirRecep>Santiago</DirRecep>
    <CmnaRecep>Santiago</CmnaRecep>
    <CiudadRecep>Santiago</CiudadRecep>
   </Receptor>
   <Totales>
    <MntNeto>19327</MntNeto>
    <TasaIVA>19</TasaIVA>
    <IVA>3672</IVA>
    <MntTotal>22999</MntTotal>
   </Totales>
  </Encabezado>
        <Detalle>
            <NroLinDet>1</NroLinDet>
            <CdgItem>
                <TpoCodigo>INT1</TpoCodigo>
                <VlrCodigo>011</VlrCodigo>
            </CdgItem>
            <NmbItem>Parlantes Multimedia 180W.</NmbItem>
            <DscItem/>
            <QtyItem>20</QtyItem>
            <PrcItem>4500</PrcItem>
            <MontoItem>90000</MontoItem>
        </Detalle>
        <Detalle>
            <NroLinDet>2</NroLinDet>
            <CdgItem>
                <TpoCodigo>INT1</TpoCodigo>
                <VlrCodigo>0231</VlrCodigo>
            </CdgItem>
            <NmbItem>Mouse Inalambrico PS/2</NmbItem>
            <DscItem/>
            <QtyItem>1</QtyItem>
            <PrcItem>5000</PrcItem>
            <MontoItem>5000</MontoItem>
        </Detalle>
        <Detalle>
            <NroLinDet>3</NroLinDet>
            <CdgItem>
                <TpoCodigo>INT1</TpoCodigo>
                <VlrCodigo>1515</VlrCodigo>
            </CdgItem>
            <NmbItem>Caja de Diskettes 10 Unidades</NmbItem>
            <DscItem/>
            <QtyItem>5</QtyItem>
            <PrcItem>1000</PrcItem>
            <MontoItem>5000</MontoItem>
        </Detalle>
  <TED version="1.0">
   <DD>
    <RE>88888888-8</RE>
    <TD>33</TD>
    <F>52725</F>
    <FE>2016-10-04</FE>
    <RR>76576212-K</RR>
    <RSR>E-SERVICE SPA</RSR>
    <MNT>22999</MNT>
    <IT1>SET INTERCAMBIO NUMERO 705929</IT1>
    <CAF version="1.0">
     <DA>
      <RE>88888888-8</RE>
      <RS>EMPRESA DE PRUEBA</RS>
      <TD>33</TD>
      <RNG>
       <D>17479</D>
       <H>17901</H>
      </RNG>
      <FA>2004-03-30</FA>
      <RSAPK>
       <M>umn8PR3gbC1L3CFheZb5Woh2bj51lvaN2OnwFdTncKXFutekvIAxPmso9DRhgQKJOjlKS1TEKxvzPAYIeEf3tw==</M>
       <E>Aw==</E>
      </RSAPK>
      <IDK>1</IDK>
     </DA>
     <FRMA algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">FVGanT5jYLSopnBQt7+t48aoLtKTYtFZHCV3c2Z2V3XAdExCke7XXONn9N4Lq1BPR24vnH/qCyvIxaYBVCtEMw==</FRMA>
    </CAF>
    <TSTED>2016-10-04T14:01:13</TSTED>
   </DD>
   <FRMT algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">V+YvYUaHFLHuOVg/n5aRxNSgcTkFj2DbGvlH5iyema8h42BNil8f7ewbk7rr5V+a1ShBHcXxU9DjDHWFnQ9p2w==</FRMT>
  </TED>
  <TmstFirma>2016-10-04T14:01:13</TmstFirma>
 </Documento>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="#T33">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>LwtihgKaAyu3Szq+NW/QiPHjm24=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>
bnp4e4f6iFP2SG6bplb13aVcf0VUC4ugqmB3GEF4kr2r6AVn+TpcvCGARwpqckUXJZTJ1eXPHKgy
2y79oO3sotyBvGTJG2lDtFhIYvB/7ntKSN4Y1YdTC8t3kscVVB2DPA8CPcX4NVx873o1w46RO/5Z
XZo/rMThRs1w6uG/mRhLQJ5MdXwl38PC46Ji0q9ERKGxDVIufAWpM6joc3Bra7hMFqQcdqH0RQWu
Jo1Ue7gCBzZK1hA2HcxUP5IS5ZJ6UrZU6qLAaqJRChw9auXTTpnxY9SSBL5cy4CRReO3U9dVxReK
WtJ6jPyh1FpsNvkFWMzrEMxu0nE48PLSCw9WAA==
</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<KeyValue>
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>
muHYq0PQCNG/sSdh+7bcDh3QFr8RGSRezbJErsC3um9weS1HbHuISNQjPIuJFmfzwA+Zdly1w3bC
HSDs1RGpN6wuqe5aM/q0YThDNGVA2UC5NJk+krYRYs3VtxhvprXa8J1C8MIKD+yTie72OcA15xiE
+s+LaMBg9v8/qJoXaeuTLkYcAAx52yVX2vpE4bIpfOZVkQEVQq2zVxgdhjNGGbCQC4pNR9t7Yn8B
lbWnQeaqSaB9ikDDz3T+QiLNbA9NAPjFW7m+WIQ8A8HtxpdaLLyBudqptSqhwTlSKu6tjdC/ZL+8
PnRWye87/MS7MLlfGWQ55BRqyn+rxxkb9QqIaQ==
</Modulus>
<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
</KeyValue>
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>
MIIEgzCCA2ugAwIBAgIBQzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCBpTEUMBIGA1UEAxMLU0lJLUNBLTIwMTMx
GjAYBgNVBAcTEVNhbnRpYWdvIGRlIENoaWxlMR0wGwYDVQQIExRSZWdpb24gTWV0cm9wb2xpdGFu
YTELMAkGA1UEBhMCQ0wxHDAaBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWDXNpaS1jYUBzaWkuY2wxJzAlBgNVBAoTHlNl
cnZpY2lvIGRlIEltcHVlc3RvcyBJbnRlcm5vczAeFw0xNTAzMjcxNTM3MzdaFw0xNzAzMjYxNTM3
MzdaMIHwMSQwIgYDVQQLExtTdWJkaXJlY2Npb24gZGUgSW5mb3JtYXRpY2ExJzAlBgNVBAoTHlNl
cnZpY2lvIGRlIEltcHVlc3RvcyBJbnRlcm5vczELMAkGA1UEBhMCQ0wxHTAbBgNVBAgTFFJlZ2lv
biBNZXRyb3BvbGl0YW5hMRowGAYDVQQHExFTYW50aWFnbyBkZSBDaGlsZTEmMCQGCSqGSIb3DQEJ
ARYXU0lJX2R0ZV9pbXByZXNvc0BzaWkuY2wxLzAtBgNVBAMTJlBSVUVCQSBTT1BPUlRFIEZBQ1RV
UkEgRUxFQ1RST05JQ0EgU0lJMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAmuHYq0PQ
CNG/sSdh+7bcDh3QFr8RGSRezbJErsC3um9weS1HbHuISNQjPIuJFmfzwA+Zdly1w3bCHSDs1RGp
N6wuqe5aM/q0YThDNGVA2UC5NJk+krYRYs3VtxhvprXa8J1C8MIKD+yTie72OcA15xiE+s+LaMBg
9v8/qJoXaeuTLkYcAAx52yVX2vpE4bIpfOZVkQEVQq2zVxgdhjNGGbCQC4pNR9t7Yn8BlbWnQeaq
SaB9ikDDz3T+QiLNbA9NAPjFW7m+WIQ8A8HtxpdaLLyBudqptSqhwTlSKu6tjdC/ZL+8PnRWye87
/MS7MLlfGWQ55BRqyn+rxxkb9QqIaQIDAQABo3EwbzAJBgNVHRMEAjAAMD0GA1UdEQQ2MDSgGAYI
KwYBBAHBAQGgDBMKNDUwMDAwNTItM6AYBggrBgEEAcEBA6AMEwo2MDgwMzAwMC1LMCMGA1UdEgQc
MBqgGAYIKwYBBAHBAQKgDBMKNjA4MDMwMDAtSzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEASo7TMMU3Vi0C
meIOQ3k85daCtbRLA5jzmoyGdVXZmF4ibgeRmsoKBzwBA5IciI25XWhnuhNQZECC4lg45I5cEFWN
7Jn90ZEDwtOIifmAemmrx1TzcK2gflM2eLub3Do9WcCAqjh9Xs7SUnhfH0ExhqWJYKXe+TeJJmwV
HRae9A+wIB56f8UroMGrHKwFdKOPCLtk7Unr3I9sisQsRPeEYMRuxJXKPR49ZDi9tbD7Cku/GCoK
qB4g+kJCOGZAjuESRjWR8FyfJEQ3OjdAO9hBoQj+SVrrgnJkOFcH1ue2BAVOMLKUAlWkVlcoCSV1
ip01mMmoZOXlzx6hhAfajFrwiA==
</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature></DTE><DTE xmlns="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte" version="1.0">
 <Documento ID="T35">
  <Encabezado>
   <IdDoc>
    <TipoDTE>33</TipoDTE>
    <Folio>52726</Folio>
    <FchEmis>2013-06-21</FchEmis>
   </IdDoc>
   <Emisor>
    <RUTEmisor>88888888-8</RUTEmisor>
    <RznSoc>EMPRESA DE PRUEBA</RznSoc>
    <GiroEmis>Informatica</GiroEmis>
    <Acteco>1</Acteco>
    <CdgSIISucur>59529595</CdgSIISucur>
    <DirOrigen>Teatinos 120</DirOrigen>
    <CmnaOrigen>Santiago</CmnaOrigen>
    <CiudadOrigen>Santiago</CiudadOrigen>
   </Emisor>
   <Receptor>
    <RUTRecep>69507000-4</RUTRecep>
    <RznSocRecep>RUT DE PRUEBA PORTAL</RznSocRecep>
    <GiroRecep>Comercial</GiroRecep>
    <DirRecep>Santiago</DirRecep>
    <CmnaRecep>Santiago</CmnaRecep>
    <CiudadRecep>Santiago</CiudadRecep>
   </Receptor>
   <Totales>
    <MntNeto>26327</MntNeto>
    <TasaIVA>19</TasaIVA>
    <IVA>5002</IVA>
    <MntTotal>31329</MntTotal>
   </Totales>
  </Encabezado>
        <Detalle>
            <NroLinDet>1</NroLinDet>
            <CdgItem>
                <TpoCodigo>INT1</TpoCodigo>
                <VlrCodigo>011</VlrCodigo>
            </CdgItem>
            <NmbItem>Parlantes Multimedia 180W.</NmbItem>
            <DscItem/>
            <QtyItem>20</QtyItem>
            <PrcItem>4500</PrcItem>
            <MontoItem>90000</MontoItem>
        </Detalle>
        <Detalle>
            <NroLinDet>2</NroLinDet>
            <CdgItem>
                <TpoCodigo>INT1</TpoCodigo>
                <VlrCodigo>0231</VlrCodigo>
            </CdgItem>
            <NmbItem>Mouse Inalambrico PS/2</NmbItem>
            <DscItem/>
            <QtyItem>1</QtyItem>
            <PrcItem>5000</PrcItem>
            <MontoItem>5000</MontoItem>
        </Detalle>
        <Detalle>
            <NroLinDet>3</NroLinDet>
            <CdgItem>
                <TpoCodigo>INT1</TpoCodigo>
                <VlrCodigo>1515</VlrCodigo>
            </CdgItem>
            <NmbItem>Caja de Diskettes 10 Unidades</NmbItem>
            <DscItem/>
            <QtyItem>5</QtyItem>
            <PrcItem>1000</PrcItem>
            <MontoItem>5000</MontoItem>
        </Detalle>
  <TED version="1.0">
   <DD>
    <RE>88888888-8</RE>
    <TD>33</TD>
    <F>52726</F>
    <FE>2013-06-21</FE>
    <RR>69507000-4</RR>
    <RSR>RUT DE PRUEBA PORTAL</RSR>
    <MNT>31329</MNT>
    <IT1>SET INTERCAMBIO NUMERO 705929</IT1>
    <CAF version="1.0">
     <DA>
      <RE>88888888-8</RE>
      <RS>EMPRESA DE PRUEBA</RS>
      <TD>33</TD>
      <RNG>
       <D>17479</D>
       <H>17901</H>
      </RNG>
      <FA>2004-03-30</FA>
      <RSAPK>
       <M>umn8PR3gbC1L3CFheZb5Woh2bj51lvaN2OnwFdTncKXFutekvIAxPmso9DRhgQKJOjlKS1TEKxvzPAYIeEf3tw==</M>
       <E>Aw==</E>
      </RSAPK>
      <IDK>1</IDK>
     </DA>
     <FRMA algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">FVGanT5jYLSopnBQt7+t48aoLtKTYtFZHCV3c2Z2V3XAdExCke7XXONn9N4Lq1BPR24vnH/qCyvIxaYBVCtEMw==</FRMA>
    </CAF>
    <TSTED>2016-10-04T14:01:13</TSTED>
   </DD>
   <FRMT algoritmo="SHA1withRSA">V+YvYUaHFLHuOVg/n5aRxNSgcTkFj2DbGvlH5iyema8h42BNil8f7ewbk7rr5V+a1ShBHcXxU9DjDHWFnQ9p2w==</FRMT>
  </TED>
  <TmstFirma>2016-10-04T14:01:13</TmstFirma>
 </Documento>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="#T35">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>GrgWYwI8pTMvAnLJqJAEoK7VGQA=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>
Zo2tHz/pCm+60Kop0VHmfr/+ppdnvRCgGbytgUf0yPj43C3G/mKzNJsE97x4lfaCGBw9bpY8ql70
pdOpash7+S/6iyNJI8KuBVQa4HNdtQB92sh3Of5DzHoKVc+qgmgk2y9IgVsm+16tyzShTlBhg0Aw
6s4AWElg0Ui7Gox6u3A2iuk50MDmIoqOjt2u1sl6IqFMSmGlzeH4vuzkXT+qNSy5EZ+ZwD52ipEH
NNN3QEtlBtI3+h7qvZ7e8Iroy+sFG8Odhy06KaJBPKLC5YouMl3xG4mcuF/hbgkAp1CYRSWs31ub
CbnWAMCsfu8lmnLwN3YUe/cnfoz8oNU69mSl4g==
</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<KeyValue>
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>
muHYq0PQCNG/sSdh+7bcDh3QFr8RGSRezbJErsC3um9weS1HbHuISNQjPIuJFmfzwA+Zdly1w3bC
HSDs1RGpN6wuqe5aM/q0YThDNGVA2UC5NJk+krYRYs3VtxhvprXa8J1C8MIKD+yTie72OcA15xiE
+s+LaMBg9v8/qJoXaeuTLkYcAAx52yVX2vpE4bIpfOZVkQEVQq2zVxgdhjNGGbCQC4pNR9t7Yn8B
lbWnQeaqSaB9ikDDz3T+QiLNbA9NAPjFW7m+WIQ8A8HtxpdaLLyBudqptSqhwTlSKu6tjdC/ZL+8
PnRWye87/MS7MLlfGWQ55BRqyn+rxxkb9QqIaQ==
</Modulus>
<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
</KeyValue>
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature></DTE></SetDTE>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="#SetDoc">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>VZqUefe4hYx9epyMteRTgGX1umk=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>
SglAbtDkgzxDPDJUeTfhZ4Rhri+d2Wo3mpC5VhnxSl6com7kododDm07zOqCPnTV7qEuP3PSDXeW
OHu+sTZfFV10EhM4eWs5HsEM8s3ncLvJYtDWi2uXlV6gJTN/p0hq1wQBwID6+pP7NHzitI7oDNMp
XIJ6gKvpUzvvmZm8/Uyirw3wbkjoK206ghFMOrwo/XechNqs+nkIjZxLqz5mQInhsr2Z96i30syF
jb3Fgbb5vNsOtnKJ6dtvvarRDzxneIAp3gttZDn9d1uCQMt5CxcQi3ipOMYgqsyW6DxX1hgMgMwV
SdSDD4pJ3xWyUfb4L4eQaN9ESOnh6P3sie3IKQ==
</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<KeyValue>
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>
muHYq0PQCNG/sSdh+7bcDh3QFr8RGSRezbJErsC3um9weS1HbHuISNQjPIuJFmfzwA+Zdly1w3bC
HSDs1RGpN6wuqe5aM/q0YThDNGVA2UC5NJk+krYRYs3VtxhvprXa8J1C8MIKD+yTie72OcA15xiE
+s+LaMBg9v8/qJoXaeuTLkYcAAx52yVX2vpE4bIpfOZVkQEVQq2zVxgdhjNGGbCQC4pNR9t7Yn8B
lbWnQeaqSaB9ikDDz3T+QiLNbA9NAPjFW7m+WIQ8A8HtxpdaLLyBudqptSqhwTlSKu6tjdC/ZL+8
PnRWye87/MS7MLlfGWQ55BRqyn+rxxkb9QqIaQ==
</Modulus>
<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
</KeyValue>
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature></EnvioDTE>
```

Comment: Leave your pedantic rantings at the door @Parfait. If you think PHP is a real language you don't belong here.

Comment: Oscar: how did you think any language — R… XSLT… any one — would be able to magically discern what you need? This is elbow grease work to get to the nodes you need.

Comment: I have no problem to work hard to get a result. Also, I don't expect magic results. I just ran out of ideas to solve the problem. I'm sorry if I caused that impression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't grab attributes, but it may be a quick workaround for your problem:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(ndjson)
library(xml2)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

doc <- read_xml("~/data/doc.xml")
ns <- xml_ns_rename(xml_ns(doc), d1="a1", d2="a2", d3="a3")

documents <- xml_find_all(doc, ".//a2:DTE/a2:Documento", ns)
map_df(documents, function(x) {
  as_list(x) %>% toJSON() %>% ndjson::flatten()
}) %>% glimpse()
## Observations: 2
## Variables: 66
## $ Detalle.1.CdgItem.TpoCodigo.0.0     <chr> "INT1", "INT1"
## $ Detalle.1.CdgItem.VlrCodigo.0.0     <chr> "0231", "0231"
## $ Detalle.1.DscItem                   <int> NA, NA
## $ Detalle.1.MontoItem.0.0             <chr> "5000", "5000"
## $ Detalle.1.NmbItem.0.0               <chr> "Mouse Inalambrico PS/2", ...
## $ Detalle.1.NroLinDet.0.0             <chr> "2", "2"
## $ Detalle.1.PrcItem.0.0               <chr> "5000", "5000"
## $ Detalle.1.QtyItem.0.0               <chr> "1", "1"
## $ Detalle.2.CdgItem.TpoCodigo.0.0     <chr> "INT1", "INT1"
## $ Detalle.2.CdgItem.VlrCodigo.0.0     <chr> "1515", "1515"
## $ Detalle.2.DscItem                   <int> NA, NA
## $ Detalle.2.MontoItem.0.0             <chr> "5000", "5000"
## $ Detalle.2.NmbItem.0.0               <chr> "Caja de Diskettes 10 Unid...
## $ Detalle.2.NroLinDet.0.0             <chr> "3", "3"
## $ Detalle.2.PrcItem.0.0               <chr> "1000", "1000"
## $ Detalle.2.QtyItem.0.0               <chr> "5", "5"
## $ Detalle.CdgItem.TpoCodigo.0.0       <chr> "INT1", "INT1"
## $ Detalle.CdgItem.VlrCodigo.0.0       <chr> "011", "011"
## $ Detalle.DscItem                     <int> NA, NA
## $ Detalle.MontoItem.0.0               <chr> "90000", "90000"
## $ Detalle.NmbItem.0.0                 <chr> "Parlantes Multimedia 180W...
## $ Detalle.NroLinDet.0.0               <chr> "1", "1"
## $ Detalle.PrcItem.0.0                 <chr> "4500", "4500"
## $ Detalle.QtyItem.0.0                 <chr> "20", "20"
## $ Encabezado.Emisor.Acteco.0.0        <chr> "1", "1"
## $ Encabezado.Emisor.CdgSIISucur.0.0   <chr> "59529595", "59529595"
## $ Encabezado.Emisor.CiudadOrigen.0.0  <chr> "Santiago", "Santiago"
## $ Encabezado.Emisor.CmnaOrigen.0.0    <chr> "Santiago", "Santiago"
## $ Encabezado.Emisor.DirOrigen.0.0     <chr> "Teatinos 120", "Teatinos ...
## $ Encabezado.Emisor.GiroEmis.0.0      <chr> "Informatica", "Informatica"
## $ Encabezado.Emisor.RUTEmisor.0.0     <chr> "88888888-8", "88888888-8"
## $ Encabezado.Emisor.RznSoc.0.0        <chr> "EMPRESA DE PRUEBA", "EMPR...
## $ Encabezado.IdDoc.FchEmis.0.0        <chr> "2016-10-04", "2013-06-21"
## $ Encabezado.IdDoc.Folio.0.0          <chr> "52725", "52726"
## $ Encabezado.IdDoc.TipoDTE.0.0        <chr> "33", "33"
## $ Encabezado.Receptor.CiudadRecep.0.0 <chr> "Santiago", "Santiago"
## $ Encabezado.Receptor.CmnaRecep.0.0   <chr> "Santiago", "Santiago"
## $ Encabezado.Receptor.DirRecep.0.0    <chr> "Santiago", "Santiago"
## $ Encabezado.Receptor.GiroRecep.0.0   <chr> "Comercial", "Comercial"
## $ Encabezado.Receptor.RUTRecep.0.0    <chr> "76576212-K", "69507000-4"
## $ Encabezado.Receptor.RznSocRecep.0.0 <chr> "E-SERVICE SPA", "RUT DE P...
## $ Encabezado.Totales.IVA.0.0          <chr> "3672", "5002"
## $ Encabezado.Totales.MntNeto.0.0      <chr> "19327", "26327"
## $ Encabezado.Totales.MntTotal.0.0     <chr> "22999", "31329"
## $ Encabezado.Totales.TasaIVA.0.0      <chr> "19", "19"
## $ TED.DD.CAF.DA.FA.0.0                <chr> "2004-03-30", "2004-03-30"
## $ TED.DD.CAF.DA.IDK.0.0               <chr> "1", "1"
## $ TED.DD.CAF.DA.RE.0.0                <chr> "88888888-8", "88888888-8"
## $ TED.DD.CAF.DA.RNG.D.0.0             <chr> "17479", "17479"
## $ TED.DD.CAF.DA.RNG.H.0.0             <chr> "17901", "17901"
## $ TED.DD.CAF.DA.RS.0.0                <chr> "EMPRESA DE PRUEBA", "EMPR...
## $ TED.DD.CAF.DA.RSAPK.E.0.0           <chr> "Aw==", "Aw=="
## $ TED.DD.CAF.DA.RSAPK.M.0.0           <chr> "umn8PR3gbC1L3CFheZb5Woh2b...
## $ TED.DD.CAF.DA.TD.0.0                <chr> "33", "33"
## $ TED.DD.CAF.FRMA.0.0                 <chr> "FVGanT5jYLSopnBQt7+t48aoL...
## $ TED.DD.F.0.0                        <chr> "52725", "52726"
## $ TED.DD.FE.0.0                       <chr> "2016-10-04", "2013-06-21"
## $ TED.DD.IT1.0.0                      <chr> "SET INTERCAMBIO NUMERO 70...
## $ TED.DD.MNT.0.0                      <chr> "22999", "31329"
## $ TED.DD.RE.0.0                       <chr> "88888888-8", "88888888-8"
## $ TED.DD.RR.0.0                       <chr> "76576212-K", "69507000-4"
## $ TED.DD.RSR.0.0                      <chr> "E-SERVICE SPA", "RUT DE P...
## $ TED.DD.TD.0.0                       <chr> "33", "33"
## $ TED.DD.TSTED.0.0                    <chr> "2016-10-04T14:01:13", "20...
## $ TED.FRMT.0.0                        <chr> "V+YvYUaHFLHuOVg/n5aRxNSgc...
## $ TmstFirma.0.0                       <chr> "2016-10-04T14:01:13", "20...


signatures <- xml_find_all(doc, ".//a2:DTE/a3:Signature", ns)
map_df(signatures, function(x) {
  as_list(x) %>% toJSON() %>% ndjson::flatten()
}) %>% glimpse()
## Observations: 2
## Variables: 9
## $ KeyInfo.KeyValue.RSAKeyValue.Exponent.0.0 <chr> "AQAB", "AQAB"
## $ KeyInfo.KeyValue.RSAKeyValue.Modulus.0.0  <chr> "\nmuHYq0PQCNG/sSdh+...
## $ KeyInfo.X509Data.X509Certificate.0.0      <chr> "\nMIIEgzCCA2ugAwIBA...
## $ SignatureValue.0.0                        <chr> "\nbnp4e4f6iFP2SG6bp...
## $ SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod         <int> NA, NA
## $ SignedInfo.Reference.DigestMethod         <int> NA, NA
## $ SignedInfo.Reference.DigestValue.0.0      <chr> "LwtihgKaAyu3Szq+NW/...
## $ SignedInfo.Reference.Transforms.Transform <int> NA, NA
## $ SignedInfo.SignatureMethod                <int> NA, NA
```

There are other methods for flattening crazy lists into a data frame as well (many on SO).